# MySQL on remote machine accessed via chromebook terminal returns nonsense unicode which persists after I leave MySQL

Tags: mysql, unicode, chromebook

I am using the terminal in a chromebook to ssh into a remote server.  When I run a MySQL (5.6) select query, sometimes one of the fields will return nonsense unicode (when the field should return an email address) and change the MySQL prompt from:

mysql>

to

└≤⎽─┌>

and whatever text I type is converted into weird unicode.  The problem persists even after I exit MySQL

Answer (score 2):

One of the values in your database happened to have the sequence of bytes 0x1B, 0x28, 0x30 (`ESC` `)` `0`) in it. When you did the query, MySQL printed this byte sequence directly to your console. You can reproduce the effect by typing from python:

```
>>> print '\x1B\x28\x30'
```

Consoles use control characters (in particular 0x1B, `ESC`) as a way to allow applications to control aspects of the console other than pure text, such as colours and cursor movements. This behaviour is inherited from the old dumb-terminal devices that they are pretending to be (which is why they are also known as terminal emulators), along with some weirder tricks that we probably don't need any more. One of those is to switch permanently between different character sets (considered encodings, now, but this long predates Unicode).

One of those alternative character sets is the [DEC Special Graphics Character Set](http://vt100.net/docs/vt220-rm/table2-4.html) which it looks like you have here. In this character set the byte 0x6D, usually used in ASCII for `m`, comes out as the graphical character `└`.

You could in principle reset your terminal to normal ASCII by printing a byte sequence 0x1B, 0x28, 0x42 (`ESC` `)` `B`), but this tends to be a pain to arrange when your console is displaying rubbish.

There are potentially other ways your console can become confused; it's not, in general safe to print arbitrary binary data to the console. There even used to be nastier things you could do with the console by faking keyboard input, which made this a security problem, but today it's just an annoyance factor.

However, one wouldn't normally expect to have any control codes in an e-mail address field. I suggest the application using the database should be doing some validation on the input it receives, and dropping or blocking all control codes (other than potentially newlines where necessary).

As a quick hack to clean this field for the specific case of the `ESC` character, you could do something like:

```
UPDATE things SET email=REPLACE(email, CHAR(0x1B), '');
```